# Sequelize Many-to-many table with identical foreign key is overriding the value

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following structure:

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING
});

var Post = sequelize.define('post', {
  text: DataTypes.STRING
});

var PostComment = sequelize.define('postComment', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  comment: DataTypes.TEXT
});

Post.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'postUserComment', through: PostComment });
User.belongsToMany(Post, { through: PostComment });
```

The same user, should be able to make multiples comments to the same post.
But when i execute

```
post.addPostUserComment(currentUserId, {comment: "teste"})
```

If i already have a comment to this post made by the currentUser, it override it's "comment" value in the database when it should create a new row.

Dialect: mysql
Sequelize version: ~3.24.2

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`belongsToMany` means many-to-many relation, it ensure that one post will join with one user through only one row in PostComment. It doesn't violate many-to-many relation principle, because post can also has relation with other user through another row in PostComment. So in your case when user is able to add multiple comments to one post you should define following associations:

`Post.hasMany(PostComment);`

`User.hasMany(PostComment);`

and adding comments will looks like this:

```
post.addPostComment({userId: currentUserId, comment: 'test'})
```

Comment: I have to give up and do it by your way, i was able to create new instances but i was not being able to select them all. your solution worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I end up doing

```
Post.belongsToMany(User, {as: 'postUserComment', through: {model: models.PostComment, unique: false}, foreignKey: 'idPost'});

User.belongsToMany(Post, {through: {model: models.PostComment, unique: false}, foreignKey: 'idUserComment'});
```

I am able to create multiples comments now. 
I am having a little trouble to select them all, but it's something to another issue i belive.

Comment: I had to do it by @tilov-yrys way because i was able to create new instances but not select them